# Fatal Error while Importing Class/Interface from the Same Namespace

Tags: php, namespaces, composer-php, autoloader, psr-4

I have a Duck Interface (abstract class in this case) and Class MallardDuck is implementing it. I'm trying to autoload files from the `Duck` name space but gets a fatal error.

```
PHP Fatal error:  Interface 'Duck\Duck' not found in /var/www/HeadFirstDesignPattern/MallardDuck.php on line 11
```

I'm used to of working in Laravel which loads files for me, but I want to do it myself using composer. I know it's not a very big issue but when you don't know something then it's considered as a really big problem. Anyways here is the code of my classes and `composer.json`

**Duck class code:**

```
<?php namespace Duck;

//Duck.php

/**
* Description of Duck
*
* @author me
*/
abstract class Duck {

    public abstract function display();

    public function quack() {
        echo 'quack';
    }

    public function swim() {
        echo 'swim';
    }

}
```

**Mallard Duck Code**

```
//MallardDuck.php

use Duck\Duck;
/**
 * Description of MallardDuck
 *
 * @author mkhuram
 */
class MallardDuck implements \Duck{
    public function display() {
        echo __NAMESPACE__;
        echo "\n".__CLASS__;
    }
}

$md = new MallardDuck();

$md->display();
```

Compser.json File

```
{
    "name": "vendor/head-first-design-pattern",
    "description": "Description of project HeadFirstDesignPattern.",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "me",
            "email": "my@email.com"
        }
    ],
    "require": {},
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4":{
            "Duck\\": ""
        }
    }
}
```

`"Duck\\": ""` is pointing to root of my app. Here is my app directory structure:

```
vendor
    autoload.php
app
    Duck.php
    MallardDuck.php
```

Comment: Side note: `Duck` is a class, not an interface so you should extend it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot `implement` an abstract class, you can only `extend` it.